# How to log messages (raw XML) in middle-tier WCF scenario?

Tags: wcf, logging, message, middle-tier

I have a client (C) which consume WCF service (S) which is middle-tier service consuming external web service (ES).
I have control over the WCF service (S) which I have developed.

The test department would like to test the whole scenario: C <-> S <-> ES, so they are interested to view the XML raw format of transmitted messages.

How to log / view raw xml messages between C and S for testing purposes?
How to log / view raw xml messages between S and ES for testing purposes?

I have tried to configured WCF diagnostic message logging and view the result in scvtraceview BUT it there is so much Information that I cannot found the simple request/response xml :/

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has a tool that lets you see the raw SOAP request and response for WCF operations. It's called WcfTestClient.exe and on my computer it's in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

You give it a WCF to connect to and then use it's GUI to make the WCF calls.